# Change Active <li> Bootstrap CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'be been having a hard time changing the active style of my navigation, here is my code

```
 <nav id="myheader" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jake Balba</a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="partners.html">Web Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="partners.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Dont know what to do tried a lot of Css. Thanks!

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to apply a style to `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a`, for example:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/srYcUctkrb

Comment: thanks it work, but just a favor, can you explain it to me further, I'm just a newbie here in Bootstrap, and whats harder is im implementing it to laravel. Thanks

Comment: There's not a lot to explain, this is basic CSS, not Bootstrap.

Comment: i'm having a hard time to understand this one  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> whats with the space between nav and navbar-nav? does this mean that there are two classes in one UL? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: Is there anything else you need for this question?